# Qt - Is there an equivalent to C# WaitHandle.WaitAny(EventWaitHandle [])?

Tags: multithreading, qt

I'm programming a multiplexer class that basically needs to wait until one of the sources notify that it has a packet to process. In C# I can do this with

```
WaitHandle.WaitAny(handle_array)
```

where handle_array contains a WaitHandle reference to each of the source elements.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Would [QWaitCondition](http://qt-project.org/doc/qwaitcondition.html) be right for you?

Comment: Not really, because I can only wait on one condition at a time. This is alright to implement an equivalent of WaitHandle.WaitAll() because I can wait for all the sources one after another, but in my case I just need one for the quickest source to notify and process that packet.

Comment: What about `QSemaphore`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks to me that the way around this is to share only one instance of QWaitCondition across the list of threads that could emit a desired signal to wait on and depending on if we want .NET equivalents to WaitHandle.WaitAny() or WaitHandle.WaitAll() wait for *one* or *n* signals in the waiting thread. What it is really important in the later case is to ensure that all signal emits are guarded by a mutex share across all threads to ensure no signals get lost between counting a triggered signals them and setting the wait again.